# What is the best way to prevent user click anything on the form while processing on background?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, busyindicator, busy-waiting

I am working on an Youtube Mp3 converter. Mp3 converting takes a few seconds and I want the user not able to click any control on the form. I have done it using `Control.Enabled = false` for all control but I think this way is not professional and doesn't seems good for visuality. Is there any good method to do this?

Comment: Please explain this: "and doesn't seems good for visuality". Control.Enabled = false does exactly what you want, i.e., disables the user interaction.

Comment: disable the entire form, show a progressbar in marquee mode, change cursor to Busy.  take your pick, its your app

Comment: ... or show a modal dialog form.

Comment: The modal dialog would inform the user that you are working and disable the ability to interact with the form, or you can disable the form and post a message on the form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As comments says you can have a modal form:

```
yourModalForm.ShowDialog();
```

Which have no title bar buttons or no title bar at all and will close itself after conversion is done.

Or you can use `Enabled` property as yourself suggested but not for every control, you can do it for your whole form at once:

```
this.Enabled = false;
```

Remember that `this` is your form if you are in the right context.

I also suggest you to change your form cursor, like that:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

And when your work is finished all you have to do is:

```
this.Enabled = true;
this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```